# Origin of Lang's proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: mathematics, abstract-algebra, linear-algebra

Is the proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem given by Serge Lang in [*Algebra*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953854) (page 561) an original one, or has it been borrowed from some earlier sources? Who came up with it first?

(Lang's proof is closely followed by the current version of [*characteristic polynomial*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/characteristic+polynomial) page of nLab wiki.)

I am asking because I [reformulated](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.09285) it recently, and I am looking for a proper attribution.

Comment: No, the proof was quite old. It was shown in *Modern Higher Algebra* (1937) by A. Adrian Albert, and in *Vectors and Matrices (1938)* by MacDuffee.

Comment: @user1551, I checked out the proof in *Modern Higher Algebra* by Adrian Albert. No, it is not the same as the Lang's proof. For example, Adrian Albert uses *Division Algorithm* for polynomials with non-commuting matrix coefficients.